# My Netbeans 12.2 on Ubuntu only has lightweight & temporary C++ IDE, can't find the real one

Tags: netbeans-plugins

In Netbeans 12.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 (using that snap install), for my C++ plugin I have that first image.  When I try to create a new project I get that second image.  That is some kind of a lightweight version that does not do your makefiles for you.  If I try to open an existing C++ project it just never IDs any project file or folder as the right one.  And notice that this version does not include a "Create from source code".

Does anyone know how I can install the "real" c++ plugin?  I've looked in a lot of tutorials but they all say it should be there under Available Plugins, but it is not there.

[image: Netbeans C++ Plugin]

[image]

Comment: I found the answer.  It's this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/956058/c-c-option-not-available-in-netbeans

Answer (score 3):

This comes very late but it seems that Netbeans 12 lacks some components for this.

Therefore you must enable Netbeans 8.2 Plugin Portal from Plugins Settings.
Then deactivate the C/C++ and then force updates from Updates -> Check for Updates. Restart IDE and install 8.2 C/C++ plugin.

Note: I have lead into this problem now because unpack2000 is no more present.

```
The validation of downloaded plugins cannot be completed, cause: NBM ../.netbeans/12.4/update/download/org-netbeans-modules-cnd-kit.nbm needs unpack200 to process following entries: 
netbeans/modules/locale/org-netbeans-modules-cnd-kit_ja.jar.pack.gz
netbeans/modules/locale/org-netbeans-modules-cnd-kit_pt_BR.jar.pack.gz
netbeans/modules/locale/org-netbeans-modules-cnd-kit_ru.jar.pack.gz
netbeans/modules/locale/org-netbeans-modules-cnd-kit_zh_CN.jar.pack.gz
netbeans/modules/org-netbeans-modules-cnd-kit.jar.pack.gz
```

This can be resolved by installing jre-11 (if it is not present already. I have it on Opensuse Thubleweed amogst with jre-16).
So then you just start netbeans from terminal with:

```
$ netbeans --jdkhome "/usr/lib64/jvm/jre-11"
```

...and then install blugin, and when it is ready close netbeans and start it normally again.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to report that the answer from Devspain also works with Netbeans 14, in Ubuntu 22.04.